# "Operating System Not Found" error after overwriting Windows with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation

I purchased Lenovo Thinkcentre PC today, and immediately installed Ubuntu overwriting Windows. The live USB performed just dandy, but after install and prompt to reboot, I get error "No operating system found."

I reinstalled 16.04.03 over 17.10 to see if that would help, but same result. I'm not trying to dual boot or anything, just straight Ubuntu machine. I ran boot-repair. Still no success.

Comment: you installed in Legacy mode on a GPT disk. If you want Legacy boot I recommend converting the HDD to MBR partitioning and reinstalling, or Keep GPT partitioning and install in EFI mode.

Comment: I'm OK with keeping EFI and reinstalling, but how do I make sure it installs in EFI mode?

Comment: I vote for *"Keep GPT partitioning and install in EFI mode"* therefore I suggest disabling any Legacy/CSM support at UEFI settings in order to assure the installation media boots in EFI mode because "how it boots is how it installs" as put forth by the great modern philosopher OldFred.

Comment: Disabling Legacy/CSM did the trick. Thank you both!

Comment: er, oldfred used to always boot his old BIOS system using gpt partitioning with the bios_grub partition. Only MBR drive was XP install from 2006. Rod Smith convinced me of superiority of gpt back in 2010. I still suggest gpt partitioning for any drive that will not be Windows in BIOS mode as then it has to be MBR. But Ubuntu will boot BIOS or UEFI from gpt if correct supporting partitions, ESP or bios_grub are on drive. And I normally add both to every new drive or larger flash drive in gpt mode.

Answer (score 3):

[Answer copied from the comments left by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976870/no-os-found-after-install#comment1568083_976870):

> Disabling Legacy/CSM did the trick.

[image: CSM in Lenovo BIOS]

<sub>[Image credits](https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/findpost/1143/4050302/4052543)</sub>